# imprimir caracteres especiais quando gerar arquivo

Tags: java

Algumas strings estão saindo assim na hora de gerar meu .txt

```
Ã‰ fÃ¡cil entrar em contato com a Ã¡rea
```

eu leio um outro arquivo .txt que possui várias frases, eu faço um tratamento de todas as linhas e separo a parte que me interessa, dai gero um arquivo .txt
está saindo zoado assim.
tem algum modo de resolver?

```
    Reader lerArquivo = new FileReader(getNomeArquivo());
    BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(lerArquivo);

    String linha;

    while ((linha = br2.readLine()) != null) {

    }
```

//para gerar o arquivo eu uso

```
FileWriter x = new FileWriter("geraArquivo.txt", false);
x.write(organizaString);
```

Comment: É bem provável que você esteja lendo arquivos em um determinado *encoding* e tratando em outro. Por exemplo, seu arquivo é UTF-8 e a plataforma está em outra, como `FileReader` usa ao *encoding* da plataforma dá problema. Veja se o conteúdo lido também apresenta problema e se sim, tente usar `InputStream` para ler. Verifique também qual o *encoding* do seu arquivo e da sua plataforma, para ver se não são diferentes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ao invés de usar `FileReader`, use `InputStreamReader` e passe o **charset**.

Exemplo:

```
BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(
                         new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(getNomeArquivo()), "UTF8"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File arq = new File(nomeArq);

// para ler
BufferedReader leitor = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(arq.getPath()), "ISO-8859-1"));

// para escrever
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(arq.getPath()), "ISO-8859-1"));
```

Comment: Teria como explicar o que esse charset difere do `UTF8` da resposta?

Comment: Sempre que possível, comente a codificação, por exemplo o motivo de utilizar um ou outro encoding.